# Analysing a number sequence in MySQL

Tags: mysql, dataset, sequence, selection

This is certainly not a programming questions, but I hope someone is able to help.

I've been working with tha dataset / mysql database with around 1,000,000 records looking for patterns on it, avarage values, and generally, any kind of indicator.

After I've been doing queries manually for around 2 months already, I'm wondering if there's any kind of software that would execute different queries by itself?

Such as:

- Make groups of 5 rows and sum values.
- Look for the lowest value in a group,
- Look for specific sequences...

Does anyone have any clue how I could approeach this search?

I think it's important to mention that I have done a few algorithms based on query results using PHP, and Python and Keras. But I'm trying to find new patterns more than making something which the ones I already have.

Kind regards;
Chris

Comment: This would fall under data analysis and machine learning. Have a look at the [cross validation stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks Solarflare, I also posted in cross validated, and I did tried using different LSTM networks using Keras and TensorFlow. I'll ask again! Have a good one!